# Invalid application. Delete? on Nokia mobile phones

Tags: java, java-me, nokia, midp

I like a mobile game called Bounce Tales, so I chosed trying modding it. I can succesfully run it on KEmulator, but when I try to run it on a real mobile phone (Nokia 2700 Classic for example), it says: "Invalid Application. Delete?"

E: Here is the jad:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_04 (Oracle Corporation)
MIDlet-Name: Bounce Tales Hacks
MIDlet-Version: 1.0
MIDlet-Vendor: Gskartwii
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 375644
MIDlet-Jar-URL: Bounce Tales.jar
```

Comment: Yep definitely check all the `.jad` parameters, maybe post them here.  Also, at what point do you get the error?  After downloading the entire app, or straight after pointing at the jad?  How are you deploying it?  Over the air or side-loading?

Comment: When I open the folder containing the app it has no such icon. I get the error when trying to load the application.

Comment: I tried Nokia Ovi Suite and moving it to the SD card with jad. Either do not work.

Comment: I suggest you to upload your .jad file's code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! I need to use custom manifest, put the size to the JAD and use MIDlet-Permissions attribute! Here is my new JAD:

```
MIDlet-1: BounceHAX,/icon.png,RMIDlet
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 373309
MIDlet-Jar-URL: BounceHAX.jar
MIDlet-Name: BounceHAX
MIDlet-Vendor: Rovio
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MIDlet-Icon: /icon.png
MIDlet-Description: Bounce Tales Hacks
MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.rms, javax.microedition.midlet, javax.microedition.lcdui, javax.microedition.lcdui.game, javax.microedition.media, javax.microedition.media.control
```

Then here is my manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.6.0_03-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
MIDlet-Data-Size: 1024
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-Name: Bounce Tales Hacks
MIDlet-Icon: /icon.png
MIDlet-Vendor: Nokia
MIDlet-1: Bounce Tales, /icon.png, RMIDlet
MIDlet-Version: 2.0.3
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
Nokia-Platform: Nokia*
```